# Add open CV created model in my android project

Tags: android, opencv, model, artificial-intelligence

I have already created **open-CV** model. I want add this my **android** project how can I do this and please help for my project. and please give me a references in that subject area followed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For using openCV on Android, that's a big move.

I think you might want to read these first:

1. OpenCV4Android : [Official](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html),
   This provides some openCV's function that you can use it in Android(Java)
2. Android NDK : [Setup Guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/), 
   This helps you use your C/Cpp in your app.